# In pdfscreen, long table of contents in the panel

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfscreen

I need my long table of contents to be in the panel but it gets out of the panel space. Can I customize the font size of the table of contents so that the titles are smaller but they all fit in the space? Alternatively, could I have a two column panel?

A toy example is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{truncate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage[screen,panelleft,gray,paneltoc]{pdfscreen}
\margins{.75in}{.75in}{.75in}{.75in}
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
\begin{document}

\section{Song number 1}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 1 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 2}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 2 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 3}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 3 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 4}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 4 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 5}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 5 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 6}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 6 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 7}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 7 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 8}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 8 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 9}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 9 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 10}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 10 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 11}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 11 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 12}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 12 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 13}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 13 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 14}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 14 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 15}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 15 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 16}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 16 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 17}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 17 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 18}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 18 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 19}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 19 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 20}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 20 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 21}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 21 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 22}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 22 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 23}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 23 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 24}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 24 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 25}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 25 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 26}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 26 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 27}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 27 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 28}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 28 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\section{Song number 29}
\begin{quote}
This is the song\\
of the 29 little pigs\\
Have you ever seen them?
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Then I get the toc in the panel out of the screen limits. See the screenshot. I would like to have a two column toc that can fit all the items. Do you know if this is possible?

([image: screen shot])

Comment: Please could you post a Minimum (non-)Working Example which people can compile to reproduce the problem? This will increase the chances of your receiving useful responses by helping people to easily understand and work on your question.

Comment: I added the MWE.